# Is an Event running in another thread? (.Net Compact Framework)

Tags: c#, winforms, events, windows-mobile, multithreading

I'm developing a **Windows Mobile 5.0 or above** with **.Net Compact Framework 2.0 SP2** and **C#**.

when I try to access the control's width on a method that handles an event it throws me the following exception:

Control.Invoke must be used to interact with controls created on a separate thread.

Is this method running in another thread?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An event runs on the thread that fired it. So if the event was fired on a different thread than the one that created the control, it runs in a different thread, yeah.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, controls cannot be accessed by threads that have not created them. Well, to be more accurate they can if you *really* want but you risk the application locking up "randomly" due to a deadlock.

To get around this problem use the Invoke() or BeginInvoke() methods to set a callback for the "UI Thread" to pick up.

e.g.

```
private void HandleSomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(textBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        textBox1.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(HandleSomeEvent), new object[]{sender, e});
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = "WIN!";
    }
}
```